# Beaglebone Black doesn't boots up with the yocto-image

Tags: beagleboneblack, yocto

I am working on yocto-project to create images for BBB.I cloned the project `git clone -b pyro git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky` then initiated the build process. Baked it with `bitbake core-image-sato` and got the build directory with files.

I created 2 partitions on SD card with 64M for root and rest(15+GB) for boot.
Copied `MLO and u-boot-beaglebone.img` to the `root partition`.

Untared the `core-image-sato-beaglebone.tar.bz2`on root partition and then copied `zImage-beaglebone.bin, zImage-am335x-bone.dtb, zImage-am335x-boneblack.dtb` under boot partition.

When I tried to boot BBB found that u-boot expects uEnv.txt and get stuck there. The yocto build directory doesn't have any uEnv.txt, so how to write own uEnv.txt ? This is the u-boot prompt.

`Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
mmc0 is current device
micro SD card found
mmc0 is current device
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1
SD/MMC found on device 0
reading uEnv.txt
** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
** File not found /boot/uImage **
U-Boot#`

I added uEnv.txt in root partition with text as 
`mmcdev=0
mmcpart=1
bootpart=0:1`
This time u-boot tries to read a `uImage` from `/boot` directory but I have `zImage` whats this conflict now? How should I resolve it?

`SD/MMC found on device 0
reading uEnv.txt
32 bytes read in 4 ms (7.8 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from mmc ...
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
reading /boot/uImage
** Unable to read file /boot/uImage **
U-Boot#`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122526/how-to-convert-a-zimage-into-uimage-for-booting-with-u-boot

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 so you mean to say its mandatory to convert zImage in uImage and u-Boot can't load zImages ?
And what about `zImage-am335x-boneblack.dtb, zImage-am335x-bone.dtb, zImage-beaglebone.bin` do I have to convert them too?

Comment: I followed the step mentioned in the link above. This time u-Boot goes in a infinite loop while reading the uImage `data abort
pc : [<9f376478>]          lr : [<9f35a494>]
sp : 9f238060  ip : 9f238090     fp : 00000da1
r10: 00000080  r9 : 00000200     r8 : 9f238f40
r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00564a00     r5 : 00000020  r4 : 48060100
r3 : 00000000  r2 : 56190527     r1 : 00000da2  r0 : 00000001
Flags: Nzcv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32
Resetting CPU ...
resetting ...
`

Comment: You can also try `#define CONFIG_CMD_BOOTZ ` and boot the zImage via U-Boot

Answer (score 1):

It seems that U-boot is not able to find the uEnv.txt file. Try these configurations. You might need to modify some of the configuration based on your environment.

`sudo vim uEnv.txt`

```
kernel_file=zImage
bootdir=/boot
mmcdev=0
mmcpart=2
loadzimage=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootdir}/${kernel_file}
loadfdt=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${fdtaddr} ${bootdir}/${fdtfile}   
console=ttyO0,115200n8  
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro  
mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc  
mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} root=${mmcroot}  rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype} ${optargs}  
uenvcmd=run loadzimage; run loadfdt; run mmcargs; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
```

Copy zImage and dtb to the boot partition :

```
sudo cp -v /<path_to_kernel>/arch/arm/boot/zImage <path_to_boot>/boot/
sudo cp -v /<path_to_kernel>/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dtb <path_to_boot>/boot/
```

Comment: No luck I got this `Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from mmc ...
Running uenvcmd ...
reading /boot/zImage
** Unable to read file /boot/zImage **
reading /boot/am335x-boneblack.dtb
** Unable to read file /boot/am335x-boneblack.dtb **
Bad Linux ARM zImage magic!
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
** File not found /boot/uImage **
U-Boot#
`

Comment: Check that your zImage is present at /boot/zImage or not...If the path at which zImage is present is not /boot then update "bootdir" variable in uEnv.txt with the zImage path.

Comment: Its there under /boot directory.See in boot partition I have `MLO, uEnv.txt and u-boot.img` and in root partition under /boot directory I have `am335x-boneblack.dtb, am335x-bone.dtb and zImage`

Comment: This helped a bit, but not get stuck at starting kernel
`reading uEnv.txt
477 bytes read in 4 ms (116.2 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from mmc ...
Running uenvcmd ...
5655192 bytes read in 986 ms (5.5 MiB/s)
34643 bytes read in 53 ms (637.7 KiB/s)
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 80f80000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80f80000
   Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f8b752
Starting kernel ...
`

Comment: how do you write in uEnv.txt .
Means what information do we need to pass. Is there any instruction about writing uEnv.txt ?

Comment: While U-boot is executing, type any key to get u-boot prompt. Type "printenv". All the variables and command that u-boot uses will be displayed. You can update those variables by either writing to uEnv.txt or using U-boot commands.

Comment: oky, but I am still stuck at the same point. BBB dosen't boots up